# Java Regex Matching Strings

Tags: java, regex

Basically I'm trying to match a string inside of a string in Java. For example, I'd want to match "hello" in "hello!there!hello!", matching all of the hellos.

I currently have this but it's not working:

```
if(word.matches(wordToMatch)) {
word = word.replaceAll(wordToMatch, plugin.greenyPhrases.get(wordToMatch));
}
```

Any help would be majorly appreciated!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
String word = "hello!there!hello!";
word = word.replaceAll("hello", "replaced");
```

edit: heres the full String class notation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: It also accepts true regex expressions.  :) remember to pay the door man an accept hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matcher.find() to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the regex engine through the matches method, you need to use .*

```
String word = "hello!there!hello!";
String requestedWord = "hello"

if( word.matches( ".*" + requestedWord + ".*" ) )
{
    System.out.println( " This will be printed " );
}
```

Best